# Determine all complex numbers $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z + 2 - i| \leq |\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm working on the following problem:

Determine all complex numbers $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$ with $$|z + 2 - i| \leq |\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i|$$

I get stuck after the first few lines:

$|z + 2 - i| \leq |\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i|$

$ = (x + 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 \leq (x + \sqrt{2})^2 + (y - \sqrt{2})^2$

$ = x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2 -2y + 1 \leq x^2 + 2\sqrt{2}x + 2 + y^2 - 2\sqrt{2}y + 2$

$ = 4x - 2\sqrt{2}x - 2y - 2\sqrt{y} \leq -1$

I think I am supposed to bring this into a form $$(x + a)^2 + (y + b)^2 \leq r$$ but I don't know how to factorize the last line.

Comment: You want to say :
$$\left|z + 2 - i\right| \leq \left|z + \sqrt{2} - i\sqrt{2}\right| \, ?$$

Comment: Let $A(a)$, $B(b)$ and $M(z)$. 
$$\left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} / |z - a| \leq |z - b|\right\}$$ 
is the set of point $M$ such that $MA \leq MB$ witch means that $M$ is close to $A$ than $B$. It's the half of plane that contain $A$ and delimited by the perpendicular bisector of the segment $[AB]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since$\left|\sqrt2-\sqrt2i\right|=2$, your set is the circle centered at $-2+i$ with radius $2$. If you want to write $z$ as $x+yi$, it's$$\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\middle|\,(x+2)^2+(y-1)^2=2\right\}.$$

Comment: Where does the $-2 +i$ for the circle center come from?

Comment: From the fact that $z+2-i=z-(-2+i)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it
\begin{align*}
|z + 2 - i| \leq |\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i|= \sqrt{2}|1 - i| & \Longleftrightarrow 
\sqrt{(x + 2)^{2} + (y - 1)^{2}} \leq 2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + 2)^{2} + (y - 1)^{2} \leq 4
\end{align*}

which is the equation of a circle centered at $(-2,1)$ whose radius equals $2$.

We could have shortened the conclusion by interpreting the proposed relation geometrically.

In fact, the function $|\cdot|:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is a norm which induces a metric as $d(w,z) = |z - w|$ whenever $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence the proposed relation can be interpreted as the set of points whose distance to $-2 + i$ is at most $r = |\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i| = 2$ (which is a circle).

Hopefully this helps !